# Trust me, I'm not stealing

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Don't look on your face for ME!
>
> For, you will only find my cousin.
>
> Don't watch out for me in the city!
>
> For you will find my other cousin.
>
> Instead, maybe look in front of you,
>
> Just fill me up and empty me continuously for the most satisfaction.
>
> Freeze me and I may pop, yet scald me and I will be just fine.
>
> Yes I can be small, but one of my three is big enough for YOU!

Comment: Water's cousins are vapor and ice. I think

Comment: Those are cousins for sure :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it a

> Coffee Mug

Don't look on your face for ME!

For, you will only find my cousin.

> "Mug" is slang for Face

Don't watch out for me in the city!

For you will find my other cousin.

> If you are in the city you can get "Mugged"

Instead, maybe look in front of you,

Just fill me up and empty me continuously for the most satisfaction.

> A coffee mug is likely nearby for anyone at a PC, you fill it up multiple times a day to stay awake and satisfied.

Freeze me and I may pop, yet scald me and I will be just fine.

> If you freeze a mug with liquid in it, it can burst. But they are fine to boil liquids (scald)

Yes I can be small, but one of my three is big enough for YOU!

> There are three letters, and one of them is "U"

Title:

> I'm not stealing is another hint at "Mugging"

Comment: This is the correct answer. You got all the parts, so just wait for the check tomorrow :D

Comment: another thought: nyfb gur funcr bs gur unaqyr vf hfhnyyl va n h, fb gung jnl LBH pna teno vg.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be

> **Eyes**?

`Don't look on your face for ME!` 
 `For, you will only find my cousin.`

> You can only see from your eyes, so you can't look at your own face unless you are looking at a **reflection**. They can be a cousin because when you look at one, it looks right back at you. Also, ME could stand for **My Eyes** ([MY EYES!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qn977W9HjWM)), and a synonym for ME is I, which sounds like **eye**.

`Don't watch out for me in the city!` 
 `For you will find my other cousin.`

> There are many buildings in a city, wherefore there are many **windows** in the city. It is said that eyes are the windows of the soul. You can also **watch** things go by from a window.

`Instead, maybe look in front of you,` 
 `Just fill me up and empty me continuously for the most satisfaction.`

> In front of the word **you** is **y** which sounds like **eye**. In fact, the thing closest in **front** of you that you can see, is your nose. The nose can act as the **y** and the two eyes can be the **e**'s, joining together to make **eye**. Also, the word **you** sounds like **U**, and the first letter after U is **V** which can stand for **vision** or **view** (view, sounds like VU.). 
>  
>  And when people's eyes get **filled** with tears, it can be a bit satisfying (relieving is a better word) to cry and let it all out.

`Freeze me and I may pop, yet scald me and I will be just fine.` 
 `Yes I can be small, but one of my three is big enough for YOU!`

> Most people who daydream can have their eyes focused too much (or **frozen**) where they can also get a mind blank (a **pop**). I am unsure about the scalding part, but there are eye drops that can **sting** your eyes, though they are good for them, too. 
>  
>  Yes, eyes are small (24 mm, which is smaller than an average size gumball!) and also the word **small** rhymes with **ball**, linking to **eyeball**. The word **eye** has **three** letters, the letter **y** being big enough for the word **YOU** (since it contains a **y**).

---

**Title:**

`Trust me, I'm not stealing`

> You can **steal** a glance with your eyes; sometimes you must keep a **close eye** on something before it is **stolen**; there is a pop band called [**Stealing** Sheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stealing_Sheep) which made a song called [Shut **Eye**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeUEUT2NtG0); some people stare into your eyes to see whether or not you are telling the truth (i.e. to be sure if they can **trust** you); and again, the world **I** in **I'm** sounds like **eye**.

Comment: I like the creativity :D +1